# Cannot run newman on jenkins [newman :command not found] in AWS EC2 Linux Jenkin machine

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, amazon-ec2

I am getting below error when i try to run from Jenkin shell script

[Collection_run] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7542658729538318661.sh
+ newman -version
/tmp/jenkins7542658729538318661.sh: line 2: newman: command not found
Build step ‘Execute shell’ marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Still from AWS EC2 Linux prompt i am getting proper response

Installed below from Command line and set path, From command line things are fine

npm
node
newman

newman --version

From jenkin i want to run Postman collection as i could able to run from command line

Answer (score 0):

The PATH variable jenkins uses is probably different than the command line path you set.

To set the PATH variable in Jenkins:

1. go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties
2. Check Environment Variables if not already
3. If PATH is already specified append an entry (: delimiter).  If not already specified add an entry with a Name of PATH and Value of $PATH:/your/path/to/newman.
4. save configuration then restart Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Find This Path and Copy:
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman
Go To:
Control Panel\System and Security\System - Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > System variables > choose the (Path) > Edit > New and paste there:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error

1. go to **Manage Jenkins** > select **Manage Plugins** > select **Install** and search "**NodeJS**".
2. After that go to **Manage Jenkins** > select **Global Tools Configuration** > scroll down and you can find "NodeJS" > Click on **Add NodeJS** > wrote " newman newman-reporter-htmlextra " in **Global npm packages to install** section. it will 1st excute "npm install -g newman" then excute "npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra".> then apply and save
3. After that build your project